# How can I rename files within dir(s) to their respective dir name while maintaining extensions of files?

Tags: files, zsh, rename, mv

I have a bunch of directories with different names within the current directory:

```
Hello World/
Dr. Dre - Still Dre/
Angry Birds/
2018 Grand Prix Race Highlights/
```

And within each of those directories are files (one in each, respectively):

```
source.c
song.aac
setup.apk
spanish.mp4
```

And I want to rename each file to their directory name but the extension shouldn't change. Sample output files:

```
Hello World.c
Dr. Dre - Still Dre.aac
Angry Birds.apk
2018 Grand Prix Race Highlights.mp4
```

Output location does not matter.

I've found so many solutions for renaming files within the current dir that use `for file in *` and `mv "$file" "${file/oldname/newname}"` but my files are in subdirectories 1 level deep so what I currently have is:

```bsh
currdir=$(pwd)
for dir in */
do
  cd ${dir}
  file=$(echo *)
  ext=${file##*.}
  mv "*" "${dir}.${ext}"
  cd ${currdir}
done
```

I'm using zsh and when I try to run this function I get `zsh: source.c not found` which I suspect might be something wrong with the line `file=$(echo *)`. I also don't like the complication of what I did there so maybe there's a cleaner way of doing it or even a one-liner. I only want to use commands which are already installed by default in Ubuntu such as `mv`, `find`, `sed`, `vim`, `grep`, etc. The directory names might have symbol characters like `$`, `&`, `.`, etc. so please accommodate weird names also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd just do:

```
autoload zmv
zmv '(*)/(*)(.*)' '$1$3'
```